# Android. Show all devices and all emulators with one command from command line

Tags: android, android-emulator

Windows 10 (64 bit)

If I want to print all devices I use command:

```
adb devices
```

If I want to print all AVDs I use command:

```
emulator -list-avds
```

OK. But I need one command that print all devices and all emulators.

Comment: On a unix machine, you could define an alias, e.g.: `alias all-devices='adb devices && emulator -list-avds’`. I’m sure other platforms support this too.

Comment: I'm  use Windows 10

Comment: directly run "adb devices -l && emulator -list-avds" in command prompt.

Comment: Thanks. It's work:  adb devices & emulator -list-avds